# Ansible - how can I be sure only specific packages installed in Linux system

Tags: ansible

I would like to use Ansible to make sure specific packages installed in the Linux system, but in addition I would like to make sure no extra packages are installed. In order words, if I want only the packages: unzip, vim, tcsh, etc installed. I would like to be inform if package that not in this list installed and I may want to remove it.

Is there any way to do it with Ansible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the package manager the Linux OS is using. Fortunately there are modules for the major ones:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_packaging_modules.html#os

This is a snippet from the apt plugin:

```
- name: Remove "foo" package
  apt:
    name: foo
    state: absent

- name: Install the package "foo"
  apt:
    name: foo
    state: present
```

But others offer similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ansible 2.5, you can use the `package_facts` module for that:

```
vars:
  whitelist:
    - vim
    - unzip
tasks:
  - name: Get package facts
    package_facts:
      manager: apt
  - name: Install all packages in whitelist
    apt:
      name: "{{ whitelist }}"
      state: latest
  - name: Remove all packages not in whitelist
    apt:
      name: "{{ ansible_facts.packages | difference(whitelist)}}"
      state: absent
```